# is there a non-recursive feature implemented in `async`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, stack

I need to process a quite large quantity of entries (tens of thousands) with functions such as `async.each` or `async.eachSeries` or `async.whilst`.

Almost reduntant to say that I *have* to use `async` because I am going to call some queries for each entry, making the code asynchronous.

Unfortunately, using `async`'s functions, the call stack gets consumed pretty fast, leading to `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

Is there a way to tweak `async` in order to prevent this problem? An iterative implementation would solve the problem. Any alternative library that takes this problem into account?

here is an example code snippet that show the problem:

async = require('async');

```
a = []
for(i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    a[i] = i;
}

async.eachSeries(a,function(element,callback) {
    console.log(element);
    callback();
},function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log("error:",err);
    }
    console.log("finished.");
});
```

Comment: No, but by using your own stack, you can usually restate recursive methods without recursion. Provide more code, and I'll provide an answer...

Comment: Here is the code of the script, sorry if it's a bit messy, it's undergoing a refactoring: http://nopaste.info/ca0c118591.html

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `tail recursion`. Check this question: [What is tail recursion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/what-is-tail-recursion)

Comment: I am using `async`, so I am not the one that should implement this. I don't think `async` makes use of tail recursion.

Comment: @fstab so, your function passed to `async` is not recursive?

Comment: not in itself, but, for example, it's made recursive by `async.whilst`, via composition of multiple functions